# Find names of all generated HTML files in Sphinx extension

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to create a simple Sphinx extension which post-processes generated HTML files after they're created by HTML builder. I have written a post-processing routine using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4), but then I faced a trouble converting my routine into a separate Sphinx extension.

I've registered my handler for [`"build-finished"`](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/appapi.html#event-build-finished) event using [`app.connect`](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.connect), but I still cannot figure out how to get the list of filenames to preprocess.

- How to get the list of all HTML files which were generated? *(or, at least)*
- How to get the output directory? I've found that I can use [`env.found_docs`](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/envapi.html#sphinx.environment.BuildEnvironment.found_docs) and [`builder.get_target_uri`](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/builderapi.html#sphinx.builders.Builder.get_target_uri) to obtain the relative path of generated page, but I need the directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mentioned in Sphinx documentation for some reason, but the path to output directory can be easily found as `app.outdir`. After discovering this fact, it was easy to gather all the filenames I needed:

```
def process_build_finished(app, exception):    
    if exception is not None:
        return

    target_files = []
    for doc in app.env.found_docs:
        target_filename = app.builder.get_target_uri(doc)
        target_filename = os.path.join(app.outdir, target_filename)
        target_filename = os.path.abspath(target_filename)
        target_files.append(target_filename)

    ...
```